# VBA Out of Memory error on simple copy-paste macro

Tags: excel, vba, out-of-memory

I am running a really simple copy-paste macro to break circular references in excel. It equals some offset of the range "facilityPaste" to "facilityCopy". However, everytime this is run, I get 2 "Out of Memory" errors. I have tried looking for an answer everywhere but for some reason cannot resolve this.

So far I have tried renaming the named ranges, and specifying everything to be a .Value, but to no avail.

The identical code used to not throw any errors before. As it's part of a larger (confidential) block of code, would it be possible that the error is caused by something else? Note that the error occurs also when run separately.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT 1: The errors are thrown regardless of what code is actually ran. Perhaps this is a different problem altogether? To confirm, the code execute correctly.

```
Sub [redacted]()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Range("facilityCopy").Offset(, Range("Case").Value).Value = Range("facilityCopy").Value
    Calculate
    
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

Comment: `offset of the range "facilityPaste" to "facilityCopy"`  - looks like you're referencing "facilityCopy" twice though?  Any event handlers attached to the affected range(s) ?

Comment: Do the above 6 lines of code fail when you run it?  What are the two Range-s? And the value at the Offset?

Comment: Hi @TimWilliams No event handlers. What do you mean with referencing facilityCopy twice?

Comment: @donPablo The code runs and does its purpose, but it gives me the errors at the end if I run it separately. The ranges refer to a small [1,x] range which it copies a set number of columns to the right depending on the case number.

Comment: Seems the problem is more likely to be in your other code.